# mysqldump exporta solo una tabla y no todas - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy utilizando mysqldump en mi cmd para exportar toda una base de datos, el problema es que al ejecutar este código, solo exporta la primera tabla y no las demás. He estado averiguando acerca de este problema y no encontré ningún tipo de solución. El código es el siguiente:

```
mysqldump -u root bancos > C:\xampp\htdocs\backupdb\backup\bancos.sql
```

En donde mis tablas son estas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al exportarlo, el resultado vendría a ser el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán solo exporta la primera tabla y no las demás, no se si esto sucedería por la poca memoria que tengo en mi ordenador o la versión de MySQL que tengo, mi sistema operativo es Windows 10, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Prueba con la opción `--debug` para ver si falla algo. Lo otro, revisa que todas las tablas estén en el mismo tablespace y si no, usa la opción `--all-tablespaces`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda, he estado averiguando un poco con la información que me brindó usted, hasta que encontré el problema, decía lo siguiente: `Unknown table "column_statistics" in information_schema (1109)`, entonces averigüé más sobre esto y mi código (junto con la solución) resultó ser así:  `mysqldump -u root bancos > C:\xampp\htdocs\backupdb\backup\bancos.sql --all-tablespaces --column-statistics=0`, tenía que agregar `--column-statistics=0` para omitir este error, ¡Muchísimas gracias!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resuelto, la solución era omitir el siguiente error:

```
Unknown table "column_statistics" in information_schema (1109)
```

Y para omitir este error, se tenía que poner lo siguiente:

```
--column-statistics=0
```

Y por último, mi código final sería así:

```
mysqldump -u root bancos > C:\xampp\htdocs\backupdb\backup\bancos.sql --all-tablespaces --column-statistics=0
```

De esta forma, el `mysqldump` omitirá este error y continuará exportando todas las tablas, muchas gracias por su ayuda.